# How do you ensure physical network interfaces always get the same interface name across reboots on an embedded Linux system?

Tags: linux, networking, embedded, ethernet

For an embedded Linux system, if I have two or more network interfaces, how do I ensure that they always get the same interface names every boot

In other words, I want, for example, eth0 to always map to one physical Ethernet port, eth1 to the next, etc.

My Linux "distribution" is home-grown, and I use devtmpfs for populating /dev.  I use busybox for init (and most everything else), along with custom init scripts for system startup and shutdown.

I do not need hotplug facilities of mdev or udev -- I'm referring to "fixed" Ethernet ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me with Linux 3.9.0 on an x86_64 architecture.

```
#!/bin/sh

# This assumes the interfaces come up with default names of eth*.
# The interface names may not be correct at this point, however.
# This is just a way to get the PCI addresses of all the active
# interfaces.
PCIADDRLIST=
for dir in /sys/class/net/eth* ; do
  [ -e $dir/device ] && {
    PCIADDRLIST="`readlink -f $dir/device` ${PCIADDRLIST}"
  }
done

# Now assign the interface names from an ordered list that maps
# to the PCI addresses of each interface.

# IFNAMES could come from some config file.  "dummy" is needed because of
# my limited tr- and awk-fu.
IFNAMES="eth0 eth1 eth2 dummy"

for dir in `echo ${PCIADDRLIST} | tr " " "\n" | sort` ; do
  [ -e $dir/net/*/address ] && {
    MACADDR=`cat $dir/net/*/address`
    IFNAME=`echo $IFNAMES | awk '{print $1}'`
    IFNAMES=`echo $IFNAMES | awk '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i; }'`
    echo -n "$IFNAME "
    nameif $IFNAME mac=$MACADDR
  }
done
```