# How to statically assign network interfaces to USB Wireless LAN adapters

Tags: debian, networking, embedded, network-interface

For this system there are two WLAN USB adapters: One connects as a client always, and the other connects as an AP. I have a script that manages their operation, but in order to do that I need to assign them permanent interfaces (i.e.: The client is wlan0 and the host is wlan1). I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136282/how-do-you-ensure-physical-network-interfaces-always-get-the-same-interface-name), but it doesn't quite work for a number of reasons including that the devices on startup can be enumerated differently. This lead me to think that I'd have to use the manufacturer ID somehow (they're made by different manufacturers). How would you recommend I tie these devices permanently to the desired interfaces?

I can't use the entire mac address, because this has to work on multiple systems, but the first three groups should be the same between systems for each device because we'll install the same two wifi dongles on each system (unless availability changes).

Comment: They should have the same MAC regardless of which system they are plugged into. Just use `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` to make sure the one you want gets the name you want.

Comment: We're going to use the same MODELS of dongles, but each system will have their own, so the least significant digits will be different for each system. I know you can do some magic with the persistent rules, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you have different MODELS you should be all set. Don't use the `address` attribute at all. Just match on the other attributes. Use `udevadm` to find all the attributes of each device and then pick a subset that identifies each type. Plop these in a `70-persistent-net.rules` file and it should work.

Comment: Ah, beautiful. Thanks. That worked perfectly once I figured out how to do it. I'll post a more thorough answer here to close the question when I get a chance.

Comment: @LavaHot if you have a chance, posting the answer would be great.